# Resend/React email Next.js, Email destination[to: ] only works with my personal email address

Tags: resend.com

I managed to integrate resend and react email logic to send custom emails to my personal email address that also was used to sign in into resend web app. The issue comes when placing a different email in the `resend.emails.send({...,to:["an_email"],...})` command.

It only works for 1 email, for any other email I use, the message is not being delivered

```
 const html = render(
      CustomEmail({
        name: "miguel",
      })
    );
    console.log("html is: " + html, email);
    const res = await resend.emails.send({
      from: "Acme <onboarding@resend.dev>",
      to: [email],
      subject: "Titebond email verification",
      // html: "<strong>It works!</strong>",
      html,
    });
```

Comment: I don't know that specific provider, but to prevent spamming, you probably have to undergo some verification process before you can send to other recipients than yourself.

Comment: Other than that: do you get any error message or is the message just not appearing at the recipient even though it's marked as delivered?

Comment: No error messages show up either it's marked as delivered in the resend dashboard when using a different recipient. I'm going to go over the process of DNS verification for my domain and check out if that fix the issue which makes sense